# Problems with: T[] b = (T[]) new Object[n];

Tags: java, generics

```
public class MergeSort
{
    /**
     * @param a Array to be sorted.
     * @param n Last element to be sorted.
     * @return void.
     */
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a, int n)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @param inp Input Array.
     * @param out Output Array.
     * @param first First index.
     * @param mid Middle index.
     * @param last Last index.
     * @return void.
     */
    private static <T extends Comparable<T>>
            void merge(T[] inp, T[] out, int first, int mid, int last)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Hello everyone I need some help.

The above is the outline my professor gave us. My problem is I want to create a, T[] b , array in the sort method so I can reuse the two arrays 'a' and 'b' when I pass them to the merge method. Instead of creating a temp array in merge everytime I call it. I've tried

```
T[] b = (T[]) new Object[n];
```

And the class will compile but when I call the sort method from my main class with an Integer array I get:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;

What can I do?
Any help would be much apreciated and if I missed this answer anywhere, my apoligies. I've been searching for the most part of the day. Thank You!

Comment: Be sure to accept Daniel's answer.  It promotes the further answering of questions and gives you some karma!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the short answer is that in Java, arrays and generics don't play together very nicely.

As you already know, Java generics are implemented using type erasure, which means that while at compile time the type may be `<T extends Comparable<T>>[]`, at runtime the type is erased to its lower bound, which in this case is `Comparable[]` (using the raw type).  The type of `T[]` is *not* actually erased to `Object[]` unless that actually is the lower bound of the generic constraint.

The upshot of this is that it should be safe to say:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] b = (T[]) new Comparable<?>[n];
```

And everything should work as you expect.

Note that there are actually a lot more caveats you should be aware of if you try to mix arrays and generics.  For example, you can implement covariance and contravariance with generics by using generic wildcards (e.g. `<? extends T>` and `<? super T>`), but arrays in Java implement covariance natively (and just throw `ArrayStoreException` when you try to invalidate their type invariants).  So if you have the ability to switch from an array to generic type (`ArrayList<T>` for example will probably do what you want), then you'll find things go a lot more smoothly.

You may also find these links useful:

- [Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104)
- [How can I work around the restriction that there are no arrays whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ105)

Comment: Thanks a million man. Writing the iterative merge sort wasn't too bad, but this one problem was making me so frustrated. Take care and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since `Object` cannot be cast to `T`

```
T b = (T) new Object();
```

Thus this cannot not true either

```
T[] b = (T[]) new Object[n];
```

You can look at how `Collection.toArray(T[] a)` is implemented to create a new array of type `T`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think your reasoning is correct.  There are many cases where a cast from `Object` to `T` would be perfectly legal at compile time (although it should generate an unchecked conversion warning), but would simply fail with a `ClassCastException` at runtime.  But that has nothing to do with the actual problem that the OP is facing, which has to do with the dichotomy between parameterized types and arrays.

Comment: I agree with you Daniel and and unchecked warning is what I was expecting not an exception as I got. Thanks though Nr9 for the help.

Comment: @Nr9: You are right that it is not formally correct. But it will not crash as long as it is within the scope of T. So in practice, it is okay to use.